Traffic Model: Expansion and Compression waves using Rankine-Hugoniot condition
I am learning PDE and I meet some problems when solving one traffic model which is defined as $ u_t + (1-2u) u_x =0 $ with initial condition $ u(x,0) = f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, x<0\\ 1,x>0\end{cases} $. Since I am suggested to use methods of characteristics, consider $x=x(t)$, then the characteristic equation should be $\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = 1-2u$. Therefore, by letting $x(0)=x_0$,
$$\begin{split} x(t) = (1-2u)t+x_0 &= (1-2f(x_0))t+x_0 \\&= \begin{cases} t+x_0,x_0<0\\ -t+x_0,x_0>0 \end{cases}. \end{split} $$
And along $x(t)$, it follows that
$$ u(x,t) = u(x_0,0)=f(x_0) = \begin{cases} 0,x_0<0\\ 1,x_0>0 \end{cases}. $$
Then from $ x(t) = \begin{cases} t+x_0,x_0<0 \\ -t+x_0, x_0>0 \end{cases} $, it can be derived that
$$ u(x,t) = \begin{cases} 0,x<t\\ 1, x>-t\end{cases}. $$
Then I am required to use Rankine-Hugoniot jump condition to figure out the line of shock or conservation of momentum. But I found that I couldn't find a separating plane, and the solutions of $u(x,t) $ even overlap. So I wonder if there might be an error during my calculation.
